# PHP Mailer : MAIL not accepted from server.The following From address failed

Tags: php, imap, phpmailer

I'm having issues sending mil using PHP Mailer. I have tried two different mail servers. To one of these mail servers I have access through a local IP as well. When I use the local IP as value for the `$server` variable, things work fine and mails go through. 
But when I use the external IP for the mail server things don't work and I get the error shown below. Same is the case while using another mail server's DNS. Exact same error both times.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$server = 'mail.xxxx.com';
$smtpPort = '25';
$username = 'xxxx@xxxx.com';
$password = 'xxxxx';

$mail->isSMTP();                                        // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = $server;                      // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                 // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = $username;                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = $password;                                // SMTP password    
$mail->From = 'xxxx@xxxxxx.com';
$mail->addAddress('abijeet@xxxxx.asia', 'xxxxx');           // Add a recipient

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                          // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->isHTML(true);                           // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';

if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
```

This is the debug output from the PHPMailer for both servers when external IP or a DNS is used-

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 mail.xxxxxx.com ESMTP Postfix
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-mail.xxxxxx.com 250-PIPELINING 250-SIZE 15728640 250-VRFY 250-ETRN 250-STARTTLS 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN 250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8BITMIME 250 DSN
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
SMTP -> ERROR: MAIL not accepted from server:
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: The following From address failed: xxx@xxxxxx.comSMTP server error:
```

---

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 xxxxx.com ESMTP Citadel server ready.
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-Hello localhost (xxx.xxxxx.net [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]) 250-HELP 250-SIZE 10485760 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN 250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN 250 8BITMIME
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
SMTP -> ERROR: MAIL not accepted from server:
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: The following From address failed: abijeet@xxxx.comSMTP server error:
```

Also note that I was able to successfully connect to the DNS based mail server using Windows Live Mail, so it's not a port issue.

Comment: Well, given that the server replied basically "I reject this based on the 'from' adddress", I'd guess that that it the problem. If you're using a fake 'From:' address/domain that does not have valid MX records many servers will reject your mail.

Comment: @Sammitch, Well why does it accept the same from when a local IP address is provided as the server. Also what are MX records?

Comment: 1. Because your server is probably not set up to reject mail with an invalid sender. 2. [What is an MX record?](https://www.google.ca/search?q=what+is+an+mx+record)

Comment: @Sammitch, but it's the same server? It works when I access it through the local ip, but doesn't when I do so from the external ip.

Comment: From the machine that your PHP is running on, can you try opening a telnet connection on port 25 to the SMTP server (first by way of the local address, then by way of the public address), then proceeding with an SMTP session (follow the instructions at http://www.port25.com/how-to-check-an-smtp-connection-with-a-manual-telnet-session-2/).  It's always easier to debug SMTP problems this way, as opposed to relying on cryptic error messages from mail components - using telnet, you can see exactly how the SMTP server is responding each step of the way.

Comment: By any chance, does the domain of the FROM address have an SPF record, and is this a valid address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the version of PHP mailer and things seem to be working now. No changes had to be made to the code. The older version that was being used was **5.1**. Current version is **5.2.7**

Answer (score 1):

If you connect to the external IP address, you almost certainly get an external source address, and I suspect it's a dynamic address in your case. Well-configured email servers do not allow random external IP addresses to send mail through them.

The solution to is to use either [SMTP authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2476) or the internal address.

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial online to send mail from a local server.

This solution requires sendmail.exe (a Command Line Interface (CLI) executable which accepts email from PHP, connects to an SMTP server and sends email). You will not require to use it by command, don’t bother about it :-) Download the sendmail.zip and follow these steps:

Create a folder named “sendmail” in “C:\wamp\”.
Extract these 4 files in “sendmail” folder: “sendmail.exe”, “libeay32.dll”, “ssleay32.dll” and “sendmail.ini”.

Open the “sendmail.ini” file and configure it as following

```
    smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
    smtp_port=465
    smtp_ssl=ssl
    default_domain=localhost
    error_logfile=error.log
    debug_logfile=debug.log
    auth_username=[your_gmail_account_username]@gmail.com
    auth_password=[your_gmail_account_password]
    pop3_server=
    pop3_username=
    pop3_password=
    force_sender=
    force_recipient=
    hostname=localhost
```

You do not need to specify any value for these properties: pop3_server, pop3_username, pop3_password, force_sender, force_recipient. The error_logfile and debug_logfile settings should be kept blank if you have already sent successful email(s) otherwise size of this file will keep increasing. Enable these log file settings if you don’t get able to send email using sendmail.

```
Enable IMAP Access in your GMail’s Settings -> Forwarding and POP/IMAP -> IMAP Access:
Enable “ssl_module” module in Apache server:
Enable “php_openssl” and “php_sockets” extensions for PHP compiler:
```

Open php.ini from “C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\bin” and configure it as following (The php.ini at “C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.x” would not work) (You just need to configure the last line in the following code, prefix semicolon (;) against other lines):

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
;SMTP = 
; http://php.net/smtp-port
;smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = you@domain.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = "C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"
```

Restart WAMP Server.
Create a PHP file and write the following code in it:

```
<?php
$to       = 'recipient@yahoo.com';
$subject  = 'Testing sendmail.exe';
$message  = 'Hi, you just received an email using sendmail!';
$headers  = 'From: sender@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: sender@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
            'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
            'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
    echo "Email sent";
else
    echo "Email sending failed";
?>
```

Make appropriate changes in $to and $headers variables to set recipient, sender and reply-to address. Save it as “send-mail.php”. (You can save it anywhere or inside any sub-folder in “C:\wamp\www”.)